# Inserting formatting characters in String.Format?

Tags: vb.net, string, formatting

I googled for this, but VB.Net (2008) doesn't seem to allow inserting formatting characters (eg. \t, \r\n) in String.Format:

```
'BAD MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}{tab}{1}", "Foo", "Bar"))
'BAD MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", "Foo", "Bar"))
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}" & vbTab & "{1}", "Foo", "Bar"))
```

Is there an easier way to build a formatted string that must contain formatting characters?

Answer (score 11):

"Easier" is probably in the eye of the beholder, but here is a different way:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(vbTab, {"Foo", "Bar"}))
```

I also came up with this:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", "Foo", "Bar", "Test").Replace("\t", vbTab))
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose another option is:

```
String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}", vbTab, "Foo", "Bar", "was", "here")
```

Not the most readable, but better than `& vbTab &`.

Answer (score 2):

Using vbTab works fine (and vbCrLf etc also).

\t \n etc is fior C, not VB

{tab} is a code for SendKeys

I conclude that your 3rd line is the (only) working method unless something like this

`MessageBox.Show("Foo" & vbTab & "Bar")`

is possible: it reads easier I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions support interpolated strings to simplify it to this:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format($"{{0}}{vbTab}{{1}}", "Foo", "Bar"))
```

Or just:

```
MessageBox.Show($"{"Foo"}{vbTab}{"Bar"}")
```

Note the `$` before the first `"` (and duplicated braces in the first version).