# vb.net how to increment id if i click the button

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, auto-increment

i just want to increment id inserted with the limit equal to other table

i have no problem with that

the only problem is that, i cant code increment on id until the limit

id  column 2

1-----------0

2-----------5

3-----------0

and so on, like this, by cliking insert button,the id should increment one by one til the limit

can anyone please help me

```
    RecordDate.Text = MyFormat

    Dim antinull As Integer = Format(0)
    BadBeg.Text = antinull
    WarePcs.Text = antinull
    CustPcs.Text = antinull
    Returned.Text = antinull
    BadEnd.Text = antinull

   Try
        Str = "insert into BadWarehouseInv values("
        Str += Id.Text.Trim()
        Str += ","
        Str += """" & RecordDate.Text.Trim() & """"
        Str += ","
        Str += """" & BadBeg.Text.Trim() & """"
        Str += ","
        Str += WarePcs.Text.Trim()
        Str += ","
        Str += CustPcs.Text.Trim()
        Str += ","
        Str += Returned.Text.Trim()
        Str += ","
        Str += """" & BadEnd.Text.Trim() & """"
        Str += ")"
        Con.Open()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dst.Clear()
        Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM BadWarehouseInv ORDER BY Id", Con)
        Dad.Fill(Dst, "stock")

        Con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could Not Insert Record!!!")
        MsgBox(ex.Message & " -  " & ex.Source)
        Con.Close()
```

Comment: Please consider [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054069/inserting-formating-characters-in-string-format

Comment: Better than that please consider a parameterised query! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: @tjameson `String.Format` might be more readable, but just as susceptible to injection, you should be recommending using `SqlParameter`s instead.

Comment: @MattWilko - Yes! It took me a bit to realize that this was an SQL query. I saw a wall of string concatenations and [jumped to conclusions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRxqY4wuTHw).

Comment: those forums are very complicated, i want simple and understandable, it will be used for my redefense in system anaylys and development, i have no time left,plssssss :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but:-

Usually when you are writing to a database you have one column which is an [Identity type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column) and is the unique identifier in the table or [Primary Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key). This automatically increments when a new row is added.

So when you create a new row in the table you let the database engine worry about this and then use [a technique to read this value back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791156/return-last-id-identity-on-insert-row-vb-net-mysql)

If you don't want to use an identity column you could use a query to find the current highest number and then add one to it. This is not recommended because you may have two clients doing this at the same time and so one will fail when it tries to write to the database.